# Firebase Analytics logEvent typescript error

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase SDK version 8.0.2 and trying to log a 'screen_view' event but I'm getting an error that says:

> Argument of type '"screen_view"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"add_payment_info"'

The linter seems like it's not reading the correct string value.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (subscribeActive) {
            analytics.logEvent('screen_view')
        }
}, [subscribeActive])
```

Related Github link, though OP doesn't specify how he fixed it: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. There are non-optional properties in the eventParams object for a 'screen_view' event. Without the app_name & screen_name it produces the typescript error I described--weird how the error doesn't specify missing properties, but instead throws a misleading error.

```
logEvent(
      eventName: 'screen_view',
      eventParams: {
        app_name: string;
        screen_name: EventParams['screen_name'];
        app_id?: string;
        app_version?: string;
        app_installer_id?: string;
        [key: string]: any;
      },
      options?: firebase.analytics.AnalyticsCallOptions
    ): void;
```